# QueryTables Destination using Dim sheet and cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to excluse the use of `Select` in my script. I have no problem with most issues, but the `QueryTables` is stumping me

Here is my current code

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
Set rng = Cells(2, 1)

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add _
        (Connection:="TEXT;N:\Operations\001 Daily Management\PPL Check Report\FMSQRY.CSV" _
        , Destination:=rng)
```

I'm well aware that normally I would use:

`Destination:=Worksheets("Data").Range("A:2")`

but when I try and use

`Destination:=ws.rng` I just get an method error

Clearly a very simple issue, but it's going right over my head currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the worksheet when assigning the range variable:

```
Set rng = ws.Cells(2, 1)
```

Comment: Yeah, totally missed that... Changing `With ActiveSheet.QueryTables` to `With ws.QueryTables` will fix the next error too